# How is synchorization issue being handled in this file?

Tags: synchronization, gson

I am considering using Gson for my project. While reviewing its features, a question arose regarding its concurrency handling.

How does Gson handle potential concurrency issues in its implementation? If multiple threads access the same feature using getters or setters, could this lead to problems? Or is this issue addressed elsewhere within the library?

The file I am refering to is listed below

[NonNullElementWrapperList.java](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/main/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/NonNullElementWrapperList.java)

I manually reviewe the file but have no idea where its applied. Addtionally clueless where this issue is being handled at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

> I manually reviewe the file but have no idea where its applied

`NonNullElementWrapperList` is an internal class which is used by the method [`JsonArray.asList()`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/JsonArray.html#asList()). There are no guarantees about whether it is thread-safe.

In general you should consider all Gson classes and methods to not be thread-safe unless their documentation explicitly says so.

The documentation currently only guarantees that the [`Gson` class](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/Gson.html) is thread-safe:

> Gson instances are Thread-safe so you can reuse them freely across multiple threads.

For `TypeAdapter`, `JsonSerializer` and `JsonDeserializer` the documentation recommends that implementations should be thread-safe, but Gson cannot enforce that custom user-defined implementations adhere to this.